# Writing Text Copying Previous Data

Tags: java

So I have (maybe trivial) a problem that I can't solve. So I am collecting some sensor data using from an Android (Sensor etc. are [standard libraries](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html)) device that goes like this (pretty much standard):

```
private final SensorEventListener MultiSensorListener
            = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    // Printing of data to screen happens here. File will be written here async.
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
            String sensorReading = "\nLight Reading: " + String.valueOf(event.values[0]);
            side_output.append(sensorReading);                
        }
        //previous code, let's assume that both or any one has been done
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY) {
            //textLIGHT_reading.setText("LIGHT: " + event.values[0]);
            side_output.append("\nProximity Reading: " + String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
        }
        if()...

        // Many more can go
    }
};
```

So what I want is this: First, initially get all the sensor values `event.values[index]` when `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` is triggered and then create a `string` table (csv, maybe stored in a static variable).

For the example below lets assume that first one is `Acclerometer`, then `Gyro` lastly `Ambient Light` etc. viz:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| event.values[0]    | event.values[0]    | event.values[0]    |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| event.values[new]  | copy from previous | copy from previous |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| copy from previous | event.values[new]  | copy from previous |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

What happens here is:

1. Populate the first row with the first read values
2. For every `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` update the row for that specific sensor and copy the unchanged values from  the previous sensors.

How can this be done? I tried string manipulation and using `+=` but fact is with huge data, handling is becoming a big problem and I really don't want my data collection to be slow just for that!

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Can each `Sensor` object store its own most recent reading? Then the logic in the event handler can simply request the value from the `Sensor`.

Comment: I think not! This is the standard Android library I am using: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

Comment: @Jeet.Deir but nothing prevents you from wrapping each Sensor with your custom-class that will do the additional logging.

Comment: @alfasin Can you show a minimal, compilable example? It would be great help! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, now I did my research!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add methods to your sensor listener or any other object that you're instantiating using anonymous-class, then call these logging methods in your logic:

```
private final SensorEventListener MultiSensorListener
            = new SensorEventListener() {

    // the overriden methods here ...

    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    private void logHistory(String key, String value) {
        // ...
        // for example:
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    private Map<String, String> getLoggedHistory() {
        Map<String, String> mapCopy = new HashMap<>();
        mapCopy.putAll(map);
        return mapCopy;
    }
    ...
    // Printing of data to screen happens here. File will be written here async.
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
       ...
       // log event:
       map.put(event.getId(), event); // just an example
    }
```